# ng-flow upload file - how to add to TOP of ng-repeat list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-flow

I'm using the angular ng-flow component for file upload and it's working great besides a few nuances.  I'd love to be able to have the new files that I try to upload put on the top of the list rather than on the bottom of the list so it's clear for users the latest one that has been uploaded.  I tried using the angular order by command but that doesn't seem to work unless it's an existing list compared to adding a new file to the list.

Basically I create a new row for each file once it's complete and print out the file details:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in $flow.files | orderBy:'file.name'" ng-hide="file.isComplete()">
```

the list looks like this before upload:

```
old1
old2
old3
```

then I add a new file and I see:

```
old1
old2
old3
new1
```

when I'd like:

```
new1
old1
old2
old3
```

This is probably more of a question about using Angular's ng-repeat functionality for new items added to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use [**orderBy**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter, you need just let the property in filter, as the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in $flow.files | orderBy: 'name'" ng-hide="file.isComplete()">
```

**EDIT**

Since you want to sort your items by *chronological* order, it should give you the expected result:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in files | orderBy: '$index': true">
```

Here's is a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.files = [  
     {  
        "id":1,
        "name":"Old1"
     },
     {  
        "id":2,
        "name":"Old2"
     },
     {  
        "id":3,
        "name":"Old3"
     }
  ];

  var increment = 1;
  $scope.push = function (name) {
    $scope.files.push({ "id": increment + 3, "name": name + increment++ })
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>      
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<p>Before Filter:
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="file in files">
    <td ng-bind="file.name"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<p>After Filter:
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="file in files | orderBy: '$index': true">
    <td ng-bind="file.name"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<button type="button" ng-click="push('New')">Add new file</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is fine if the files all exist.  The problem is I'm adding a new item to the list of files.  In your example the 4 files all exist as part of the array and you're just sorting on the name.  I don't want to order by the name.  I want to say if there is a new file added then it should be first rather than last regardless of it's name.  So programatically add a new file files.push({  
        "id":3,
        "name":"New1"
     }) and see where it lands in the list.

Comment: So, If I understood well now, you don't need sort items by name, it was just an attempt, what you were looking for was a way to sort by *chronological* order, right? If so, take a look at my edited answer and let me know if it's correct now.

Comment: that works great in your example and exactly what I was looking for... but with my code it doesn't behave like yours.  Could it have something to do with $index?   When I print out what a {{ file }} looks like I see a complicated object with $$hashKey:"object:56". Would I instead order by $hashKey?

Comment: No, the $index is provided by the `ng-repeat`. Can you make a simple demo to demonstrate your *issue*?

Comment: not sure how to do a simple demo with the required ng-flow directive.  Maybe that's what's causing the issue. Marked your answer as correct because it *should* fix the issue.  Maybe a problem with ng-flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter like this to achieve printing arrai in reverse order

```
app.filter('reverse', function() {
return function(items) {
return items.slice().reverse();
 };
});
```

Which can then be used like:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="file in $flow.files | reverse" ng-hide="file.isComplete()">
```

Comment: Well, if the problem was to reverse the array, she could simply do: `<tr ng-repeat="file in $flow.files | orderBy:'file.name':true" ng-hide="file.isComplete()">`, which results completely different of the expected result: "old1 old2 old3 new1".

Comment: The what is it. can you explain me ?

Comment: Yes, you can take a look below in my answer.

Comment: I'm not asking about filtering on a name attribute, i'm asking about when a new item is added to an existing array to have that new item shown first regardless of ABC order.

Comment: i think my code is doing the same thing. when you are adding the item into array it will be stored at last. so accessing the array in reverse order will do the work.